# Hide tab header in java

Tags: java, swing, tabs

I have `Tabbed Pane` with three tabs.
How to hide the header of these tabs to prevent the user from pressing on them?

I used to do it in `c#` by creating a class inherited from tab component class and then override the method to hide the tabs, but recently i switch to java and i searched a lot without reaching any result.

Comment: If you don't want tab functionality, why use a JTabbedPane? Why not use a CardLayout instead?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#appearanceapi

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i am working now on project and trying to do it in strategy design pattern, So i want one main form with all the buttons, and the tabs to contain the functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "the tabs to contain the functionality"? Will the tabs every be displayed? Please give us more detail on your actual problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the problem is i want to make the headers of the tabs to be hidden. the tabs contain tables and some input fields for the user. some buttons like back and cancel will be out of the panel, so even if the user move from tab to another, the back button will be contain the same logic. it's one back button for all the project. hope it's now clear. and thanks for replying

Comment: @IbrahimSwaiss: but if you want tab swapping functionality -- I assume that the program swaps views, not the user -- then **this is what CardLayout was built for**. Why are you not considering using CardLayout here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Testing
{
  public void buildGUI()
  {
    JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
    tp.addTab("A",getPanel("A"));
    tp.addTab("B",getPanel("B"));
    tp.addTab("C",getPanel("C"));
    //Control Header space area..
    final boolean showTabsHeader = false;
    tp.setUI(new javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalTabbedPaneUI(){
        @Override
        protected int calculateTabAreaHeight(int tabPlacement, int horizRunCount, int maxTabHeight) {
            if (showTabsHeader) {
                return super.calculateTabAreaHeight(tabPlacement, horizRunCount, maxTabHeight);
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
      protected void paintTabArea(Graphics g,int tabPlacement,int selectedIndex){}
    });

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().add(tp);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
  public JPanel getPanel(String tabText)
  {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(new JLabel(tabText));
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
        new Testing().buildGUI();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I don't like any solution which effects the established UI, as it makes the UI look weird (one set of tabs using metal, all the others using the installed UI - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer i think u're right, but since the project for me, and i was just practicing, i didn't care so much :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Here is an clean example, it works for me :

```
    JPanel panelOutils =  new JPanel();
    panelOutils.add(ongletOutils); 
    JScrollPane scrollOutils = new JScrollPane(panelOutils,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED); 
    JTabbedPane jTabbedPaneOutils = new JTabbedPane();
    // With Tab header 
    jTabbedPaneOutils.add(scrollOutils);        
    this.addTab("Outils", jTabbedPaneOutils);

    // Delete tab header  
    this.addTab("Outils", jTabbedPaneOutils.add(scrollOutils));
```